# "Miter" join in EMF image not rendered correctly by Word

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2010, vector-graphics, emf

In vector graphics, there are typically three ways how corners of a path are rendered: miter (i. e. pointy), bevel (i. e. cut off), and round:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFsGa.png) (I don't have enough rep to post images).
My goal is to create an image with Inkscape (version 0.92.2) and embed it into Microsoft Word (version 2010) in EMF format.

The above example shows how the image looks in Inkscape. When I save the image to EMF and open it with the viewer that is integrated in Windows, the result is basically the same: [Screenshot from the Windows image viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfCaH.png).

However, when I insert the image into Word, the "miter" join is rendered incorrectly and looks like the "bevel" join: [Screenshot from Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq1AE.png). The problem persists if I print the file from Word or export it as PDF. Surprisingly, if I right-click the image in Word and select "Save as image", the resulting raster image (PNG) is correct.

Given that the Windows image viewer shows the EMF as expected, it seems that it has been saved correctly by Inkscape. How can I get Word to also display it correctly?

Comment: Two more observations made while investigating the issue: (1) PowerPoint 2010 has the same problem, and (2) It is rendered correctly if an EMF+ file ist used rather than a plain EMF file. Unfortunately, it does not seem possible to export EMF+ from Inkscape.

Comment: More data points: Office 2013 on Windows 10 has the same problem. MS Paint on Windows 10 rasterizes the image correctly.

Comment: Word 2016 on Windows 7 has the same problem. Word 2016 on Mac shows the image correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Word gets the miter limit wrong. A workaround, if the miter limit is not relevant in the image, is to remove all U_EMRSETMITERLIMIT records from the EMF file. Here is [a tool to do that](https://gist.github.com/deffi/d0c05412f217c445335e35071ebd1c1c), using [libUEMF](http://libuemf.sourceforge.net/).

Interestingly, the problem does not occur if the EMF file contains any text (note that, when exporting from Inkscape, the option "Convert text to paths" must be deselected).